# Picasso getting error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty

Tags: android, api, url, feed, picasso

I am making online news using public API and using Picasso to load data from system. my application is running smoothly. however,  the application sometimes crash with the error showing that

```
 at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:332)
    at com.tonyapp.hoanguhsk.CustomAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.java:49)
    at com.tonyapp.hoanguhsk.CustomAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.java:20)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:288)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:345)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:361)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:368)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:399)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I Check at my customAdapter.java file and try to fix the error at Java:49. I try to test and use many solutions which I searched from other people having same issue with my case. Unfortunately, the error still displays. below lines is my CustomAdapter.java code:

```
 holder.text_title.setText(headlines.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.text_source.setText(headlines.get(position).getAuthor());
    holder.txt_date.setText(headlines.get(position).getPublishedAt());




    if (headlines.get(position).getUrlToImage()!=null){
        Picasso.get().load(headlines.get(position).getUrlToImage()).into(holder.img_headline);
    }

    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.OnNewsClicked(headlines.get(position));
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Webview.class);
            intent.putExtra("url",headlines.get(position).getUrl());
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Can anyone please help me how to fix this crash? thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Can you check headlines.get(position).getUrlToImage().isEmpty() or not

Comment: Yes, I tested this code like: if (headlines.get(position).getUrlToImage()!=null &&headlines.get(position).getUrlToImage().isEmpty() ){
        Picasso.get().load(headlines.get(position).getUrlToImage()).into(holder.img_headline);
    } but it doesn't work

Comment: can you print url before set to Picasso

Comment: Based on above comment. You've to check not empty. You're allowing empty string inside Picasso

Answer (score 0):

based on your code try to change the code as below

```
 if (headlines.get(position).getUrlToImage()!=null && !headlines.get(position).getUrlToImage().isEmpty()){
    Picasso.get().load(headlines.get(position).getUrlToImage()).into(holder.img_headline);
}
```